# How to set path and build a package/library

Tags: python, cmake, google-colaboratory, cmake-gui

I am trying to import a package in `google colaboratory`.

The installation instruction of that package in `Linux` is:

```
git clone https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/MultiNest
cd MultiNest/build
cmake ..
make
```

But it cannot be accepted in `google colaboratory`.

I would like to do `import pymultinest`
but we should install `MultiNest` first to be able to use it.
so we should use `git clone` and then build it.
I am not familiar with building the packages etc.

I use `git clone` and after that I use `import MultiNest` and I have no error but once I write `import pymultinest`:

```
ERROR:   Could not load MultiNest library "libmultinest.so"
ERROR:   You have to build it first,
ERROR:   and point the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to it!
ERROR:   manual: http://johannesbuchner.github.com/PyMultiNest/install.html
```

Comment: if you look at the manual as written in the ERROR output: http://johannesbuchner.github.io/PyMultiNest/install.html you have to build it with `python setup.py install` not with cmake the manual goes on with `However, installing pymultinest is not enough; MultiNest and Cuba are not included, so you will see an error like:

ERROR:   Could not load MultiNest library "libmultinest.so"
ERROR:   You have to build it first, and point the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to it!` so please have a look there first and update your question after you tried the actual manual. THX!

Comment: @Markus Onthe other hand `python setup.py install` does not work on google colab I have tested it before.

Comment: @Markus If you see my question, I am asking about the way of doing the building and setting path on google colab. Surely these ways did not work that I am asking here

Comment: MultiNest author should provide native package (i.e. platlib=True) using PEP 571.